# How to remove path to C files and other meta data from static library

Tags: c, static-libraries, unix-ar

I am making a static library from bunch multiple objects placed across directories.
When I run strings on the finally created static library I find that the names of the C files used to create the objects and their relative path also present in the output.

I don't want to expose such information.
What am I missing here ?
The command I am using is :

`ar rcs myLib.a myobj1.o myobj2.o etc`

I find it worth mentioning that I combine this library with other prebuilt library I have using thin archive method adding below

`$(AR) cqT final_thin.a lib1.a lib2.a`

`echo -e 'create final.a\n addlib final_thin.a \nsave\nend' | $(AR) -M`

Help would be appreciate

Comment: [Strip](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/strip.html) all debugging information from the library? Note that then it will be very hard to debug the library.

Comment: The archive itself normally only stores the plain object file names, without a path prefix, even if you provide one as you add the object file to the library.  The information comes from the compilation of the object files.  Why do you want to remove the debug information?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes that is what I want to achieve. .

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it in 2 steps.

1. Create a **debug** version of the library. Always compile this version with debug information available.
2. Create a **release** version of the library. Always compile this version stripping away **all** debug information.

The debug information is, obviously, what helps you debug your software (library). Some of this information is the paths of all relevant files - exactly as you noticed.

When you implemented / fixed everything, you can build the release version, which will not contain any sensitive information.

---

For the specifics of how to include / exclude the debug information, you need to study the documentation of your compiler. If it has a graphical interface, it might help you in your endeavor.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run strings on the finally created static library I find that the names of the C files used to create the objects and their relative path also present in the output.

There are at least two sources for such information:

1. The primary one is **debug information** embedded in your object files by the compiler.  That does include file names and paths to each original source file, among other things.  Avoid this by compiling without debug information and / or by `strip`ping the debug information from the objects.  Note that stripping debug information will make debugging more difficult, as various debugging tools will have less information to work with.
2. But you also mention that you are using **thin archives**.  A thin archive absolutely will contain names and paths to object files, for this is what allows it to be thin. "The paths to the elements of the archive are stored relative to the archive itself" ([GNU `ar` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ar)).  Note that the whole idea of thin archives really isn't suitable for any scenario where you would care about the presence of the paths.  They provide a minor build-time convenience, but are not very suitable for distribution or system-wide installation.